# Recursive pathing method

Tags: java

I have been working on a code designed to print out a "sum" of movments in a 2D array.
I was given a matrix with positive integers for entries, with a starting position NW and it should end at SE, and for each such path, I am asked for the total weight of this path("sum" of the relevant entries.).
To make things clearer, I required that any step be recorded as presented below.
Problem is, I have no errors but the method's first step is wrong- it always go up at first. I can't tell which step makes it happen. Can you detect any fault?

```
public class question02
{
    public static void printPathWeights(int [][] m)
    {
        pathing (m, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    private static void pathing (int [] [] m , int currH , int currV , int value)
    {
        if ( validPath( m , currH - 1 , currV ) == true ) //up
        {
            value += m[currH][currV];
            int tmp = m[currH][currV];
            m[currH][currV] = -1;
            System.out.println ("going up");
            pathing ( m , currH - 1, currV , value );
            m[currH][currV] = tmp;
        }
        if ( validPath( m , currH + 1 , currV ) == true ) //down
        {
            value += m[currH][currV];
            int tmp = m[currH][currV];
            m[currH][currV] = -1;
            System.out.println ("going down");
            pathing ( m , currH + 1, currV , value );
            m[currH][currV] = tmp;
        }
        if ( validPath( m , currH , currV - 1 ) == true ) //left
        {
            value += m[currH][currV];
            int tmp = m[currH][currV];
            m[currH][currV] = -1;
            System.out.println ("going left");
            pathing ( m , currH , currV - 1 , value );
            m[currH][currV] = tmp;
        }
        if ( validPath( m , currH , currV + 1 ) == true ) //right
        {
            value += m[currH][currV];
            int tmp = m[currH][currV];
            m[currH][currV] = -1;
            System.out.println ("going right");
            pathing ( m , currH , currV + 1 , value );
            m[currH][currV] = tmp;
        }
        if ( currH == m.length -1 && currV == m[0].length -1 ) //end
        {
            System.out.println (value);
        }
    }
    private static boolean validPath (int [] [] m , int possH , int possV )
    {
        if ( ( possH < 0 ) || ( possH >= m.length - 1 ) || ( possV < 0 ) || ( possV >= m[0].length - 1 ) )
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (m[possH][possV] == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does adjusting `currH` correspond to moving Vertically?  And `currV` Horizontally?

Comment: Well, I have tried to run your program with a sample array and the first step is "going down".

Comment: on my machine with a sample array:
new int[][] {{ 1, 2, 3, 4 },{ 5, 6, 7, 8 },{ 9, 1, 2, 3 },{ 4, 5, 6, 9 }};
the first step is "going up" which is not a valid move.

Comment: No, it isn't. It's still going down. I think the top prints simply scrolled off your console.

Comment: currH and currV are integers corresponding to "coordinates" on the array.

Comment: I wonder if your recursion not hitting the final SE square because your if statement looks like it has an error, and will never reach the SE corner since at that point possH will equal m.length-1 and consider this valid square is invalid. After all the recursion is done, the whole matrix would be marked with -1, and return false.

Try changing valid path as follows by removing the two '=' signs:
if ( ( possH < 0 ) || ( possH > m.length - 1 ) || ( possV < 0 ) || ( possV > m[0].length - 1 ) )

Comment: Oh, thanks! That fixed it.